# Need two pages with different URL inside Required Step for GA Goal

Tags: google-analytics, url, goal-tracking, goals

Have a funnel starting with an A/B test through Google Optimize.
Actually I have a redirect test because I'm testing two pages that already exist.

Because of that I need a GA Goal set as a funnel, but I need the first step:

- to be required
- to contain both the pages

I have tried also using regular expressions but I can't figure out how to track only these 2 URLs for my Step N. 1

My URL are:

- `/vsla`
- `/vslb`

I've tried also creating two different goals, one for people from `vsla` and another from people from the B version, but the final goal (my thank you page) has the same amount of Hit on both. So I really think it's not working and it's tracking only the final goal.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that it's tracking only the final page, but it doesn't mean your funnel is broken. You've run into an aspect of Google Analytics that is confusingly named. "Required" in a destination goal funnel does not mean "required for the goal to convert", it only means "required for the conversion to show in the Conversions > Goals > Funnel Visualization report".

Google Optimize doesn't need a funnel in order to assign conversions of the goal to each version of the page, however. That may be everything you need.

You can see more details through the funnel for each beginning page, but the trade-off is that your total goal conversion rate will be **inaccurate**. To get the details, create separate destination goals with the same destination but different funnels: Goal A beginning with `/vsla` and Goal B with `/vslb`. Mark the first step "required" in both cases.

Goals A and B will count the same conversions, but in the Funnel Visualization report you can separate them by funnel. With the Goal Option drop-down set to Goal A, you will see only conversions which were preceded by a visit to `/vsla`. It will give you great information about abandonment rates at each step along the funnel. Likewise you can use Goal B to learn about the performance of `/vslb`.

With more detail: The Funnel Visualization report includes all sessions that begin the funnel, whether or not they complete it (if the first step of the funnel is not marked "required", it includes all sessions that hit any page of the funnel). It has 3 columns. The middle column shows the funnel itself: you can see the percentage of page visits that continue on to the next page of the funnel. The final column will show you where you are losing people to when they abandon the funnel. The first column shows you where people were immediately before entering the funnel.

It doesn't seem likely to me that this will tell you much more than the overall conversion rate for each page does, since abandonment after getting past the first page isn't likely to vary between the two funnels by much. But it is an option!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have a problem understanding tracking in Analytics also applying your methods.

The issue is: when I open my funnel visualization I can literally see SOME hits on the final goal and some Hits on the same page "required" I'm tracking in the EXIT list.

This is really hard to me to understand!

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my answer to be a little more clear. The Funnel Visualization report will show you all sessions that start the goal funnel, whether or not they complete it. On the left you'll see where people were immediately before starting the funnel, and on the right you'll see where they go to upon abandoning the funnel. What you would be comparing is the percentage of sessions that complete the funnel after beginning it, for each page.

Comment: So, I'm on the funnel visualization of my goal "from vsla to thank you page" and I see /vsla through the (exit) on the right. What does this mean to you?
Because facebook tells me right now that I have 26 leads (people who have visited my thank you) but I have this situation, attaching a screenshot!
https://gyazo.com/294245d9eaf441975c5f2fe1e9427359
**Please, notice that vlsa became /vsloptina and vslb is now /vsloptinb. Name changed but same pattern

Comment: That screenshot says to me that of the 239 people who visited landing page A, 20 proceeded to the thank you page (bottom center of the report). That's not too far off from 26 - and GA data does not come in and get processed immediately. You'll want to wait till the following day for accurate reporting.